# Google auth server response and user id

Tags: google-signin

am trying to understand google's auth server response from `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123`. I got most of it, am only stuck with `jti` and `kid` and have no idea what they are for, some one please explain, am trying to find the authenticated user id, or doesn't google provide id for the authenticated user. Thanks in advance

[image: sample auth response]

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example response with obfuscated values?

Comment: @Gerik edited the question, note the `kid` and `jti` keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears under the hood the google authentication system is supported by Okta.  Here are the descriptions of those values from their documentation:

> JTI is a unique identifier for this access token for debugging and revocation purposes.  Type: String
>
> kid identifies the public-key used to sign the access_token. The corresponding public-key can be found via the JWKS in the discovery document. Type: String

I don't know why google doesn't have it listed in their documentation, but this should be what you need.

Sources:

https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc

https://google.github.io/google-auth-library-nodejs/interfaces/_auth_loginticket_.tokenpayload.html

Comment: so google doesn't provide authenticated user id right, like facebook does?

Comment: Actually:  sub appears to be.  Is this what you're looking for?  "sub" is an identifier for the user, unique among all Google accounts and never reused. A Google account can have multiple emails at different points in time, but the sub value is never changed. Use sub within your application as the unique-identifier key for the user.